# elementary set theory (being a member and subset of a set)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have to prove or give a counterexample for these two statements:

> For the following statements about sets $A$, $B$, and $C$, either prove the statement is true or give a counterexample to show that it is false.
>
> A. If $A \in B$ and $B \subseteq C$, then $A \subseteq C$.
>
> B. If $A \in B$ and $B \subseteq C$, then $A \in C$.

I tried to do it by creating random sets like $A = \{2\}$, $B = \{2,3\}$ and $C = \{2,3,4\}$ and so both statements would be true right? I can't think of a counterexample but I don't know how to actually prove these statements.

Also, if A was the empty set then wouldn't both statements always be true (because the empty set is a member of every other set)?

Comment: What do you mean by $A \in B$ ? Is A a set or an element?

Comment: @DomoB the question in my book says that all three are sets

Comment: The statements whose truth they want you decided are: “For all sets $A$, $B$, $C$ such that $A\in B$ and $B\subseteq$ it is true that $A\subseteq C$.” and similarly for the second.

Comment: Then what is the difference between $\in$ and $\subseteq$?

Comment: If $A \in B$, and $A$ is a set, then $B$ is a set of sets, like $\{\{1\},\{2,3\}\}$.

Comment: @DomoB It can be both. The question, as it is right now, is perfectly logical and correct.

Comment: In using $\in$, e.g. $x\in y$, the only requirement is that **$y$** is a set; **$x$** can be anything at all.

Comment: @amWhy thanks!!

Comment: @123  Just a side comment: you cannot prove a statement about some relation holding for all A, B, C, by showing only that a specific example of the relation holds.  However, you *can* disprove a universal statement about A, B, C, by providing a counter-example of sets A, B, C, for which the statement fails to hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This first statement is **false**.

A counter-example could be: $A=\{1\}$, $B=\{\{1\}\}$ and $C=\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$.

Then you have $A\in B$ and $B\subset C$, but you don't have $A\subset C$.

The second statement is **true**.

To prove it, take $A$, $B$ and $C$ meeting all the conditions. Then $A\in B\subset C$, so you do have $A\in C$ (by the definition of $\subset$).

Comment: $A$ should be a set

Comment: I wouldn'y say it's by transitivity, but rather it is simply the definition of $\subset$.

Comment: @Alberto I edited to take account of your remark.

Comment: @IttayWeiss May be that is a simpler argument indeed :)

Comment: I meant to be helpful.  Perhaps the tone was not nice.  Anyway, I'll remove my comment. Thanks for the edit!

Comment: Glad to have helped!